# JObject is adding additional double braces

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am sending JSON to a server.

**Client:**
I cleaned an xml document(removed the root & the namespaces), so I have the below xml:

```
<Node1>
  <StaffFirstName>xxxxx</StaffFirstName>
  <StaffLastName>Lxxxxx</StaffLastName>
</Node1>

var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDocument).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

**Server:**

```
public Node Post([FromBody]dynamic value)
{
  if (value != null)
    JObject jSonReceived = (JObject)value;
}
```

**value** gets the below JSON

```
{"Node1":{ "StaffFirstName":"xxxxx", "StaffLastName":"Lxxxxx" }}
```

**jSonReceived** is displaying additional curly braces:

```
{{"Node1":{ "StaffFirstName":"xxxxx", "StaffLastName":"Lxxxxx" }}}
```

**How can I remove the root curly braces?**

Comment: Are you using `watch` feature on VS? The one with additional brace is wrong syntactically, and is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @GhasanAl-Sakkaf yesI am using watch. JObject automatically adds root braces

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but I think you can ignore it. I have experience with `Watch` adding additional characters to denote strings and objects. I believe your object is just fine, because the value you posted is not a valid JSON, which I would expect JObject to throw an exception upon receiving it.